# How can I debug my Django UserCreationForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following code snippet:

```
    if form.is_valid():
        new_user = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/books/")
    else:
        print "invalid form"
```

At the moment it is printing "invalid form".  How can I do some further debugging to figure out what is actually invalid with the form?

Answer (score 0):

For errors associated with a field in the form:

```
for field, error in form.errors.items():
    print field, error
```

your form can also [have errors that are not associated with a field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/):

> Note that any errors raised by your Form.clean() override will not be associated with any field in particular. They go into a special “field” (called **all**), which you can access via the non_field_errors() method if you need to. If you want to attach errors to a specific field in the form, you will need to access the _errors attribute on the form, which is described later.

so you can use:

```
for error in form.non_field_errors():
    print error
```

to print those